# Issue running Kogito DMN TrafficViolationTest in my junit

Tags: quarkus, dmn, kogito

I imported dmn-quarkus-example project into eclipse. the project compiles and shows no errors. when I run mvn clean quarkus:dev, I was able to test the rest endpoint through postman and it works.

but my junit in my eclipse fails with 404.

I read few blogs and updated my application.properties file with the following, still no luck

```
    quarkus.http.port=9090
    %dev.quarkus.http.port=9191
    quarkus.http.test-port=8181
```

the other thing I had to do to get my junit working is added the following dependencies in the pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Eclipse is not configured properly, in general; based on the provided information not possible to even say if it's something related to Quarkus, or just a general Eclipse configuration issue.

Moreover, tested locally with Eclipse 2019-12 and no special configuration and no special plugin, running the JUnit test works out of the box correctly, in the example screenshot below running the unit test of the REST interface for Kogito on Quarkus example:
[image: Eclipse running JUnit]

Please ensure you have no Maven exclusion in your Eclipse configuration, and that Eclipse is allowing to run the necessary Maven phases with M2Eclipse (like running any Maven project with Eclipse)